# Suggestions on a method?

Tags: c#, string

I am just starting to program in C#, so I am a beginner, I've been practicing some codes and I would like your opinion on something.

I have a flying direction for a plane, e.g. ''London - Berlin'' (direction). I want to create a method that will return the first and the last consonant of the plane's starting point (London), and the first and the last consonant of the plane's destination (Berlin). I have written this, so I would like to know if it's ok, or if you have some suggestions:

```
public class Flight
{
    private string direction;

    public Flight(string direction)
    {
        this.direction = direction;
    }

    public string Consonants()
    {
        string starting = direction.Split('-')[0];
        string destination = direction.Split('-')[1];

        string startConsonants = starting.ToUpper().Replace("A", "").Replace("E", "").Replace("I", "").Replace("O", "").Replace("U", "");
        string destConsonants = destination.ToUpper().Replace("A", "").Replace("E", "").Replace("I", "").Replace("O", "").Replace("U", "");

        return string.Format("{0}{1}-{2}{3}", startConsonants[0].ToString(), startConsonants[startConsonants.Length-1].ToString(), destConsonants[0].ToString(), destConsonants[destConsonants.Length-1].ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review.

Comment: This appears to have been reposted on Code Review at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/39611/returning-consonants-of-a-planes-starting-and-ending-points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some suggestions:

1 - First point is logical. If you pass the string "London-Lebanon" the output is LN-LN which I consider invalid. With your version, you could also get an error if you pass "London-UAE".

2 - Your constructor is requiring an argument but it is not clear why. I'd suggest you pass the argument to the method that uses it and check if the argument is valid before processing as shown below.

3 - The split is repeated twice for no reason.

4 - You repeat the ToString() several times even on string arguments.

5 - You could define a private method to do the formatting. This prevents errors in case you change the rules.

Here is my version incorporating the above points (except the first):

```
 class Flight
    {

        public string Consonants(string direction)
        {
            string[] words = direction.Split('-');
            // check if the separator is missing
            if (words.Length!=2) return string.Empty; //missing separator error

            return string.Format("{0}-{1}", Replacer(words[0]),  Replacer(words[1]));
        }
        private string Replacer(string arg)
        { 
            string abr= arg.ToUpper().Replace("A", string.Empty).Replace("E", string.Empty).Replace("I", string.Empty).Replace("O", string.Empty).Replace("U", string.Empty);
            if (abr.Length < 2)
                throw new Exception(string.Format("processing error in Replacer input {0} outpur {1}", arg, abr)); // example if you pass: UAE

            return string.Format("{0}{1}", abr[0], abr[abr.Length - 1] );
        }

    }
```

Comment: I would, but it says I don't have enough reputation yet to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the upper/lower case distinction then you could use Linq to extract the info required

```
public string Consonants()
{
    string starting = direction.Split('-')[0];
    string destination = direction.Split('-')[1];

    char[] cs = new char[] {'B','C','D','F','G','H','J','K','L','M','N','P','Q','R','S','T','V','W','X','Z'};
    string startFirst = starting.ToUpper().ToCharArray().First(x => cs.Contains(x)).ToString();
    string startLast = starting.ToUpper().ToCharArray().Last(x => cs.Contains(x)).ToString();
    string destFirst = destination.ToUpper().ToCharArray().First(x => cs.Contains(x)).ToString();
    string destLast = destination.ToUpper().ToCharArray().Last(x => cs.Contains(x)).ToString();
    return string.Format("{0}{1}-{2}{3}", startFirst, startLast, destFirst, destLast);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you tell me why is this better than the code that I wrote?

Comment: @userr1311 If you're looking for information about code quality, you'll have more luck on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).  StackOverflow is more for whether code works or not.